Why do I get "not an image" when using gptel with Icicles?
I've had a problem with this "not an image" message popping up, but never a backtrace, until today, when I tried gptel. I just did M-x gptel.
Once I saw icicles was involved, I tried (icy-mode 0) and this worked; message went away, but what is this message?
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Not an image: (47 104 111 109 101 47 98 48 101 102...")
  error("Not an image: %s" (47 104 111 109 101 47 98 48 101 102 47 46 101 109 97 99 115 46 100 47 105 109 97 103 101 45 100 105 114 101 100 47 50 49 101 57 102 53 99 55 53 52 51 101 48 99 50 50 100 102 ...))
  put-image((47 104 111 109 101 47 98 48 101 102 47 46 101 109 97 99 115 46 100 47 105 109 97 103 101 45 100 105 114 101 100 47 50 49 101 57 102 53 99 55 53 52 51 101 48 99 50 50 100 102 ...) 472)
  icicle-display-candidates-in-Completions(nil nil)
  icicle-prefix-complete-1()
  icicle-prefix-complete()
  funcall-interactively(icicle-prefix-complete)
  call-interactively(icicle-prefix-complete nil nil)
  command-execute(icicle-prefix-complete)
  icicle-ORIG-read-from-minibuffer("Create or choose gptel buffer (*ChatGPT*): " "" (keymap (24 keymap (82) (70) (118 keymap (43) (45)) (105 keymap (43) (45)) (13 keymap (43) (45)) (77 keymap (43) (45)) (42 keymap (43) (45)) (109) (67108924 . bmkp-retrieve-more-icicle-search-hits) (116 . icicle-cycle-image-file-thumbnail) (27 keymap (67108924 . bmkp-retrieve-icicle-search-hits) (67108926 . bmkp-set-icicle-search-hits-bookmark) (12 . icicle-display-candidates-in-Completions)) (67108912 . icicle-recomplete-from-original-domain) (1 . icicle-toggle-annotation) (47 . icicle-toggle-expand-directory) (58 . icicle-toggle-network-drives-as-remote) (46 . icicle-dispatch-C-x.)) (46 . icicle-insert-dot-command) (22 . icicle-scroll-Completions-forward) (S-backspace . icicle-apropos-complete-and-widen) (S-return . icicle-apropos-complete-and-exit) (33554464 . icicle-apropos-complete-and-narrow) (33554433 . icicle-toggle-case-sensitivity) (30 . icicle-dispatch-C-^) (67108898 . icicle-toggle-expand-to-common-match) (67108899 . icicle-cycle-incremental-completion) (67108910 . icicle-dispatch-C-.) (67108900 . icicle-toggle-transforming) (67108924 . icicle-candidate-set-retrieve-more) (67108960 . icicle-toggle-regexp-quote) (67108908 . icicle-change-sort-order) (67108922 . icicle-candidate-set-define) (67108901 . icicle-candidate-set-swap) (67108987 . icicle-candidate-set-retrieve-persistent) (67108989 . icicle-candidate-set-save-persistently) (67108905 . icicle-candidate-set-save-more-selected) (67108904 . icicle-next-TAB-completion-method) (C-S-tab . icicle-toggle-completion-mode-keys) (67108926 . icicle-candidate-set-save-more) (67108906 . icicle-candidate-set-intersection) (67108907 . icicle-candidate-set-union) (67108909 . icicle-candidate-set-difference) (67108990 . icicle-candidate-set-complement) (33554444 . icicle-retrieve-next-input) (12 . icicle-retrieve-previous-input) (7 . icicle-abort-recursive-edit) (insert . icicle-save/unsave-candidate) (C-insert . icicle-switch-to-Completions-buf) (C-S-pause . icicle-toggle-WYSIWYG-Completions) (S-pause . icicle-toggle-highlight-saved-candidates) (C-pause . icicle-toggle-highlight-historical-candidates) (M-pause . icicle-keep-only-past-inputs) (67108988 . icicle-all-candidates-alt-action) (67108897 . icicle-all-candidates-action) (23 . icicle-kill-region) (S-delete . icicle-delete-candidate-object) (delete . icicle-remove-candidate) (C-S-return . icicle-candidate-alt-action) (M-return . icicle-candidate-read-fn-invoke) (C-S-next . icicle-next-apropos-candidate-alt-action) (C-S-prior . icicle-previous-apropos-candidate-alt-action) (C-S-end . icicle-next-prefix-candidate-alt-action) (C-S-home . icicle-previous-prefix-candidate-alt-action) (C-M-next . icicle-help-on-next-apropos-candidate) (C-M-prior . icicle-help-on-previous-apropos-candidate) ...) nil buffer-name-history "*ChatGPT*" nil)
  read-from-minibuffer("Create or choose gptel buffer (*ChatGPT*): " "" (keymap (24 keymap (82) (70) (118 keymap (43) (45)) (105 keymap (43) (45)) (13 keymap (43) (45)) (77 keymap (43) (45)) (42 keymap (43) (45)) (109) (67108924 . bmkp-retrieve-more-icicle-search-hits) (116 . icicle-cycle-image-file-thumbnail) (27 keymap (67108924 . bmkp-retrieve-icicle-search-hits) (67108926 . bmkp-set-icicle-search-hits-bookmark) (12 . icicle-display-candidates-in-Completions)) (67108912 . icicle-recomplete-from-original-domain) (1 . icicle-toggle-annotation) (47 . icicle-toggle-expand-directory) (58 . icicle-toggle-network-drives-as-remote) (46 . icicle-dispatch-C-x.)) (46 . icicle-insert-dot-command) (22 . icicle-scroll-Completions-forward) (S-backspace . icicle-apropos-complete-and-widen) (S-return . icicle-apropos-complete-and-exit) (33554464 . icicle-apropos-complete-and-narrow) (33554433 . icicle-toggle-case-sensitivity) (30 . icicle-dispatch-C-^) (67108898 . icicle-toggle-expand-to-common-match) (67108899 . icicle-cycle-incremental-completion) (67108910 . icicle-dispatch-C-.) (67108900 . icicle-toggle-transforming) (67108924 . icicle-candidate-set-retrieve-more) (67108960 . icicle-toggle-regexp-quote) (67108908 . icicle-change-sort-order) (67108922 . icicle-candidate-set-define) (67108901 . icicle-candidate-set-swap) (67108987 . icicle-candidate-set-retrieve-persistent) (67108989 . icicle-candidate-set-save-persistently) (67108905 . icicle-candidate-set-save-more-selected) (67108904 . icicle-next-TAB-completion-method) (C-S-tab . icicle-toggle-completion-mode-keys) (67108926 . icicle-candidate-set-save-more) (67108906 . icicle-candidate-set-intersection) (67108907 . icicle-candidate-set-union) (67108909 . icicle-candidate-set-difference) (67108990 . icicle-candidate-set-complement) (33554444 . icicle-retrieve-next-input) (12 . icicle-retrieve-previous-input) (7 . icicle-abort-recursive-edit) (insert . icicle-save/unsave-candidate) (C-insert . icicle-switch-to-Completions-buf) (C-S-pause . icicle-toggle-WYSIWYG-Completions) (S-pause . icicle-toggle-highlight-saved-candidates) (C-pause . icicle-toggle-highlight-historical-candidates) (M-pause . icicle-keep-only-past-inputs) (67108988 . icicle-all-candidates-alt-action) (67108897 . icicle-all-candidates-action) (23 . icicle-kill-region) (S-delete . icicle-delete-candidate-object) (delete . icicle-remove-candidate) (C-S-return . icicle-candidate-alt-action) (M-return . icicle-candidate-read-fn-invoke) (C-S-next . icicle-next-apropos-candidate-alt-action) (C-S-prior . icicle-previous-apropos-candidate-alt-action) (C-S-end . icicle-next-prefix-candidate-alt-action) (C-S-home . icicle-previous-prefix-candidate-alt-action) (C-M-next . icicle-help-on-next-apropos-candidate) (C-M-prior . icicle-help-on-previous-apropos-candidate) ...) nil buffer-name-history "*ChatGPT*" nil)
  icicle-completing-read-default("Create or choose gptel buffer (*ChatGPT*): " (("home.dot.emacs.dot.d.emacsen.org") (" *Minibuf-1*") ("automata.org") ("2024-09-12") ("*Org Agenda*") ("capture.org") ("rig.org") ("fema.org") (" *Org todo*") ("formula.org") ("station.org") ("*Group*") ("magit: 2024-09-11.emacspeak") ("*chatgpt* 4o/General") ("hydra.emacsen.nix") ("2024-09-11") ("agenda.emacs.org") ("automata.sync-conflict-20240911-175815-LURAAMN.org") ("process.org") ("2024-09-09") ("typisto.org") ("*Messages*") ("charachorder-vertical.png") ("home.dot.emacs.dot.d.emacsen.el") (" *Minibuf-0*") (" *Echo Area 0*") (" *Echo Area 1*") (" *code-conversion-work*") ("*straight-process*") ("*quelpa-build-checkout*") (" *tab-line-hscroll*") (" *copilot-balancer*") (" *pdf-info-query--escape*") (".ipa") ("*Async-native-compile-log*") (" *eldoc*") (" *org-src-fontification:emacs-lisp-mode*") (" *code-converting-work*") (" *server*") (" *org-src-fontification:text-mode*") ("magit-process: platform<b0ef>") ("magit-diff: platform") (" *tip*") ("backlog.org") ("account.org") ("grocery.org") ("quasar-tech.org") ("ai.org") ("bite.org") ("browser.org") ...) nil nil "" buffer-name-history "*ChatGPT*" nil nil)
  completing-read("Create or choose gptel buffer: " (("home.dot.emacs.dot.d.emacsen.org") (" *Minibuf-1*") ("automata.org") ("2024-09-12") ("*Org Agenda*") ("capture.org") ("rig.org") ("fema.org") (" *Org todo*") ("formula.org") ("station.org") ("*Group*") ("magit: 2024-09-11.emacspeak") ("*chatgpt* 4o/General") ("hydra.emacsen.nix") ("2024-09-11") ("agenda.emacs.org") ("automata.sync-conflict-20240911-175815-LURAAMN.org") ("process.org") ("2024-09-09") ("typisto.org") ("*Messages*") ("charachorder-vertical.png") ("home.dot.emacs.dot.d.emacsen.el") (" *Minibuf-0*") (" *Echo Area 0*") (" *Echo Area 1*") (" *code-conversion-work*") ("*straight-process*") ("*quelpa-build-checkout*") (" *tab-line-hscroll*") (" *copilot-balancer*") (" *pdf-info-query--escape*") (".ipa") ("*Async-native-compile-log*") (" *eldoc*") (" *org-src-fontification:emacs-lisp-mode*") (" *code-converting-work*") (" *server*") (" *org-src-fontification:text-mode*") ("magit-process: platform<b0ef>") ("magit-diff: platform") (" *tip*") ("backlog.org") ("account.org") ("grocery.org") ("quasar-tech.org") ("ai.org") ("bite.org") ("browser.org") ...) nil nil nil buffer-name-history "*ChatGPT*" nil)
  read-buffer("Create or choose gptel buffer: " "*ChatGPT*" nil nil)
  persp-read-buffer("Create or choose gptel buffer: " "*ChatGPT*" nil)
  read-buffer("Create or choose gptel buffer: " "*ChatGPT*" nil #f(compiled-function (b) #<bytecode 0xdb3f1208047d08>))
  byte-code("\302\303!\304\305\306\3!\10>\204\24\0\307\310\303\5D\"\210\2\311H\"\312\313\2\314\315$\3161;\0\317\306\4!\10>\2043\0\307\310\303\6\6D\"..." [cl-struct-gptel-backend-tags gptel-api-key default-value gptel-backend format "*%s*" type-of signal wrong-type-argument 1 read-buffer "Create or choose gptel buffer: " nil #f(compiled-function (b) #<bytecode 0xdb3f1208047d08>) (error user-error) gptel--get-api-key 7 read-passwd "%s API key: " use-region-p region-beginning region-end t] 8)
  call-interactively(gptel record nil)
  command-execute(gptel record)
  counsel-M-x-action("gptel")
  ivy-call()
  ivy-read("M-x " ("gptel" "tramp-cleanup-all-buffers" "tramp-cleanup-connection" "my-ssh-dired" "ssh" "my-ansi-term" "replace-spadel-at-point" "ytdl-download" "point-undo" "dogears-back" "mpc-songs-search" "mpc-playlist-add" "customize-variable" "move-spadel-backward" "better-jumper-jump-backward" "eww" "org-journal-new-entry" "package-refresh-contents" "visual-line-mode" "emacspeak-speak-line" "my-org-agenda-next-day" "chatgpt-shell" "typing-of-emacs" "etm-eww-html-to-org" "org-property-action" "ivy-previous-line-or-history" "replace-symbol-with-kill-ring" "org-edna-mode" "org-insert-subheading" "insert-escaped-kill-ring" "wg-echo-current-workgroup" "erc" "repeat" "wg-load" "detour-back" "dogears-list" "sieve-manage" "flyspell-mode" "typit-basic-test" "server-list-clients" "cc/move-word-backward" "comint-previous-prompt" "org-agenda-next-date-line" "crux-rename-buffer-and-file" "org-web-tools-archive-attach" "osg" "info" "wg-save" "org-return" "obtt-tangle" ...) :predicate counsel--M-x-externs-predicate :require-match t :history counsel-M-x-history :action counsel-M-x-action :keymap (keymap (67108908 . counsel--info-lookup-symbol) (67108910 . counsel-find-symbol)) :initial-input nil :caller counsel-M-x)
  counsel-M-x()
  funcall-interactively(counsel-M-x)
  call-interactively(counsel-M-x nil nil)
  command-execute(counsel-M-x)


Can't say. Looks like you're using multiple things at the same time (Counsel, Dired+, ...), not just Icicles.
You might want to provide a step-by-step recipe to repro it, starting from emacs -Q (no init file) -- that will likely help someone help you.
There's no Icicles code that directly issues that error msg (Not an image).
In my code, the only library that issues that message is dired+.el, function diredp-display-image. It raises that error when its argument isn't an image file, as determined by function image-file-name-regexp (which is defined in standard library image-file.el). (And in my code the only function that calls diredp-display-image is command diredp-do-display-images, and that's not called from any of my code.)
(I also know nothing about gptel; sorry.)
